# MVC 4 Controller Reference Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-controller, selectlistitem

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Test.Models;

namespace Test.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var model = new DropDownListData();
            model.DropDownListItems.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Sun", Value = "1" });
            return View(model);
        }
    }
}
```

Says that

`System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem>` does not contain a definition for 'Add' and no extension method 'Add' accepting a first argument of type `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem>` could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

What reference am I missing?

Comment: What type is your `model.DropDownListItems` property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error is trying to tell you, `IEnumerable<T>` is a read-only collection type.

If you want to mutate the collection, change it to `List<T>`.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Excellent! :) I cannot accept answer for another 10 minutes, but I will then.